# Time Series Analysis By Minute over a Year: How To Create Frame in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a .csv of 1,052,640 rows.  Each row is a reading of activity within a 1 minute interval for 2 years (7/1/2014 to 6/30/2016)

Using R, I imported the data into a dataframe like so:

```
uri = 'summary.csv'
df.visits <- read.csv(uri, header=FALSE)
names(df.visits) <- c("DateTime", "Visits")
df.visits <- data.frame(df.visits)
head(df.visits)
```

with the output

```
              DateTime Visits
1 7/1/2014 12:00:00 AM      0
2 7/1/2014 12:01:00 AM      0
3 7/1/2014 12:02:00 AM      0
```

I am trying to push that dataframe into a time series structure like this:

```
ts.visits <- ts(df.visits,frequency=525960, start=c(2014,7,1))
head(ts.visits)
```

and the output is:

```
DateTime Visits
[1,]   788041      0
[2,]   788043      0
[3,]   788045      0
[4,]   788047      0
```

My question - is 525960 the correct value to use for frequency?  What happens if there is a leap year?  Are the dateTime values ('788041') correct?  I want to do seasonality analysis by time of day, day of week, and month of year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, *ts* objects are for time series with fixed seasonal period. If you want to consider the fact that there are a varying number of seconds in a year because of leap years, you have to use something else. The package *xts* is an alternative for arbitrary observation times.

Also, the column *DateTime* in your *ts* object (actually, *mts*) are NOT the times that the object uses internally. They are treated as the observations of another time series. The actual times can be obtained with time(ts.visits).